# Conditional probability questions (homework)

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability

I copied the exact question. Can anyone check my answer? I am so confused between the choices, all of them seems to be workable.

> An company divides their customers according to how long they take to pay their bills into three groups: fast (< 1 month), slow (1 to 6 months), incredibly slow (> 6 months). From their previous records they know that the proportion of customers that are fast is 0.3, the proportion of customers paying slow is 0.65 and the proportion of customers who are incredibly slow is 0.05. 
>   Among those that are incredibly slow, half will still pay within two years, the other will never pay.
>
> Which of the following statements are true?
>
> 1. One out of 40 people never pay their bills
> 2. A customer who has not payed his bill for 1 month has probability of 0.0357 of never paying.
> 3. It's more likely that a customer pays within 6 months, than taking longer than 1 month
> 4. Given a person is fast or very slow, it is more likely that the person is very slow

My answer is 2 3 4. Reasons:

1. One out of 40 people never pay their bills. - False

   In probability terms, we usually add a #Taking the average#
2. A customer ... probability of 0.0357 of never paying. - True

   Consider reduced sample space of 0.65+0.05=0.7
   Consider chance of never paying = 0.025
   0.025/0.7=0.0357...
3. It's more likely ... taking longer than 1 month. - True

   Probability (Within 6 months) = 0.3+0.65=0.95
   Probability (Greater then 1 month) = 0.65+0.025=0.675 
   (Assumption: People who does not pay)
4. Given a person .. is very slow. - True

   By 2 cases
   P(fast)=0.3
   P(slow)=0.7

Comment: Why am I given a downvote?

Comment: Re #1: We are told that half of the 5% of very slow people never pay their bills. That's the same as saying 2.5%, or 1 in 40, never pay.  Re #4: You seem to conflate "slow" with "very slow." According to the question, only 30% + 5% are either fast or very slow.  Out of those 35% of people, 5% = 5/35 = 1/7 are very slow and 30%= 30/35 = 6/7 are fast. Which is more likely?